# Fit image to UIImageVIew in a table view cell

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I'm trying to get centered and fit and centered an image called from URL  in a UIImageVI in a table view cell with this code:

```
NSData *imageData= [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:news.image_small]];

    cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

    cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;

    cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

    cell.imageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
    cell.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;

    cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

But image is always greater than UIImageVI size. How can I solve it?

Many thanks

Froi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make the image equal to the UIImageView size, you should better replace:

```
cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

by:

```
cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```

Hope this Helps ;)