# UIImageView caching while tableviewcell height is reduced

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimage

I have `UITableview` which has custom cells with `UIImageViews`. In the `UITableview` I am increasing the height of the cell using `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method. Also i am adding method to increase cell height and revert to normal height.

When i tap on the cell the height is increasing , when i tap on the cell again (in order to make the `tableviewcell` return to default height) while in transition the image which is on `tableviewcell` is stays like its shown below and goes back to default height ..(i dont know how the image is being displayed while in transition)

```
-(void) zoomOutProperties
{
        fruitImage.frame=CGRectMake(0.0, 46.0, 320.0, 83.5);
        backgroundCellImage.frame=CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0,129.5);
        customCellView.frame=CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 129.5); // UIView
}
```

Comment: You want to cache image or not?

Comment: No i dont want to ..when i tap 2nd time .during transition from increased height to normal height the image is on top of the cell and i dont know how the image is shown

Comment: Please refer to the wall Sellers answer

Answer (score 0):

Please note ::

`[UIImage imageNamed:@""]` **caches** the image. Instead use: `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@""]`

To make the image equal to the UIImageView size, you should use:

```
cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```

Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9945160/667586

Answer (score 0):

Your numbers for the frames don't add up very well.  For instance, in zoomInProperties, you set fruitImage to have origin.y at 73.0, but its height is 82.5 (fractional pixels?) so it will end at 155.5, which is below the bottom of the customCellView which is 135.6.  If the outer cell UIView is not set to clip, then the image will draw partly into the next cell.

Also, by setting the inner frames before setting the outer customCellView, you could have 2 changes to the sizes if they have autoResizeMask applied.

Comment: Walt i have set fruitImage to have origin.y at 73.0 so that when i tap on the cell the cell height increases and the image y origin is pushed down so that it appears at center of that increased cell height

Comment: I am assuming that customCell is the UITableViewCell in question and that fruitImage is in customCell's view hierarchy (probably in customCell.contentView).

Comment: Increasing the size of a subview will not affect the size of the cell. If fruitImage overlaps customCell's boundaries and customCell is not set to clip its contents, then fruitImage will be allowed to draw past the edges of customCell. The next cell or header or footer or other app part knows nothing of this, so the fruit image stays after customCell shrinks.